# Wrapping results of ASP.NET Core WebAPI methods using IResultFilter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I have implemented a result filter like this:

```cs
public class ResultWrapperFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor))
        {
            return;
        }

        var objectResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        if (objectResult == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!(objectResult.Value is WrappedResponseBase))
        {
            objectResult.Value = new WrappedResponse(objectResult.Value);
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

The filter is used by configuring `MvcOptions` through `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(
            options => { options.Filters.AddService<ResultWrapperFilter>(); });
    services.AddMvc();

    // ... the rest is omitted for readability
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is this filter is causing `InvalidCastException`: Unable to cast object of type 'WrappedResponse' to type 'System.String' (the method in question has string as the return value type).

Am I even allowed to do this using IResultFilter?

**NOTE:** I am aware of the possibility of using middleware to accomplish the response wrapping. I don't want to use the middleware to accomplish this because the middleware doesn't have access to `context.Result as ObjectResult`. Deserializing from the response stream, wrapping and serializing again seems so unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer just came to me.
When setting `objectResult.Value`, `objectResult.DeclaredType` also needs to be set.

So in this case:

```cs
if (!(objectResult.Value is WrappedResponseBase))
{
    objectResult.Value = new WrappedResponse(objectResult.Value);
    objectResult.DeclaredType = typeof(WrappedResponse);
}
```